Crop texture along mesh with boolean modifier
I'm working on a terrain mesh wich is 117sqKm. It has a 2Gb texture on it.
I'm currently splitting the mesh using a boolean modifier in order to extract sections of interest.
Since said texture has been already synced to the heightmap that was applied to the mesh, my interest is to crop the texture along with the mesh and export that texture section only.
I'm exporting with "apply modifiers" to get this specific mesh section, since there are many mountains to do id love to get the texture section corresponding to the mesh section exported along..
Is that possible?



Yeah, I don't think there's an ezpz way to do this with a few button clicks. You could probably write a Python script to get the ratio of WxH of the bool object to the full mesh, create an image of the appropriate resolution and then unwrap the booled section and bake the texture from the large to the small mesh with that image. You could do all this semi-manually too if you only need one chunk cut out. If you wanted to repeat it though, a script would make sense.

Thanks, so far the easiest way is to bake the texture as vertex colors but im still looking for ways to achieve what i need in the end..

For who may come across this.. the next best thing is baking the texture after applying the boolean, reference here
